# Transition time doesn't work with CSS3

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website with a full background image transition.
The problem is the animation, i can't make them work properly. I want them to fade from one to another without the black screen between the images. This is my website in live: http://testes-cmt.bl.ee

I've tried a lot of things, but i can't fix this problem, even when trying to change the time.

Does anyone knows how to fix this? 
This is my code so far:

HTML:

```
<ul class="cb-slideshow">
  <li><span>Image 01</span></li>
  <li><span>Image 02</span></li>
  <li><span>Image 03</span></li>
  <li><span>Image 04</span></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.cb-slideshow li span { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: none;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 32s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: imageAnimation 32s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: imageAnimation 32s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: imageAnimation 32s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: imageAnimation 32s linear infinite 0s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li div { 
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-animation: titleAnimation 32s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: titleAnimation 32s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: titleAnimation 32s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: titleAnimation 32s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: titleAnimation 32s linear infinite 0s; 
}

.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(1) span { 
    background-image: url(../images/1.jpg) 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) span { 
    background-image: url(../images/2.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 8s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 8s;
    -o-animation-delay: 8s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 8s;
    animation-delay: 8s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) span { 
    background-image: url(../images/3.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 16s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 16s;
    -o-animation-delay: 16s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 16s;
    animation-delay: 16s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) span { 
    background-image: url(../images/4.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
    -o-animation-delay: 24s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
    animation-delay: 24s; 
}


.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) div { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 8s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 8s;
    -o-animation-delay: 8s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 8s;
    animation-delay: 8s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) div { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 16s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 16s;
    -o-animation-delay: 16s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 16s;
    animation-delay: 16s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) div { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
    -o-animation-delay: 24s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
    animation-delay: 24s; 
}


@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-o-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-ms-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest way I found to make the transitions crossfade rather than go through black was to adjust the `@keyframes` to extend the `opacity: 1` time:

```
@keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    30% { opacity: 1 }
    40% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
```

Something like this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/esturcke/rK6Js/1/).

Comment: omg.. Thanks man! I was with headache because i was unable to fix this. =D The test link is working just fine. You can check it out, testes-cmt.bl.ee Thanks again. Sorry, i can't give you a + rep. because i have less than 15.

Comment: Great, glad it works. That’s a pretty slick pure CSS slideshow you’re using.

Comment: Yeah, i know there is some JS, etc. But i want to keep my website all HTML and CSS, except for the countdown timer i want to put. But still can´t find a great tutorial for that. I'm new on the advanced technique to build a professional webdesigner.